# Not able to view the open-api documentation in chrome

Tags: java, swagger, springdoc

Dependency that we are using is our pom for openapi are as follows:

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
         <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
         <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>                                                     
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
       <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
       <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

This pom has a dependencies from other projects as well and those other projects are java maven projects.

I even tried to make changes to webSecurityConfiguration class as well like mentioned below:

```
   @Override
   public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
    .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**","/webjars/swagger-ui/**")
    
    }
```

After hitting the url http://localhost:8081/v3/api-docs or http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html
I'm getting this error:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
>
> <error_description>An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext</error_description>
> unauthorized

Comment: please ensure that the class having the `configure(WebSecuirty web)` method  extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and has the `@Configuration` annotation as well.

Comment: all these annotations are well placed already.

Comment: any exceptions in the server logs? if so add them to the question.

Comment: Could your please provide your swagger configuration?

Answer (score 0):

your configuration looks messy.
You just need:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

Here is the link for some demos:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos